# SQL partition by time while aggregrating

Tags: sql

Working on a fairly complex SQL statement, and not getting the most occurred prop_list count while aggregating across users.  Here is a sample of my dataset:

```
user_id, term_id, time_stamp, prop_list
u100, t10, 7:00, (a,b,c)
u100, t10, 7:01, (a,b)
u100, t11, 7:01, (a,b)
u101, t10, 7:00, (a,b,c)
u101, t10, 7:01, (a)
u102, t10, 6:59, (a)
```

Desired output:

```
term_id, term_id_distinct_count, prop_list
t10, 3, (a,b,c)
t11, 1, (a,b)
```

Here is my current code:

```
select 
    a.term_id,
    count(distinct user_id) as term_id_distinct_count,
    a.prop_list
from 
    (select 
         user_id, term_id,
         prop_list,
         row_number() over(partition by user_id, term_id order by time_stamp asc) as row_no
     from 
         data_table
     group ) a
where 
    a.row_no = 1;
```

Note that when a user_id had multiple term_id, we only want to use the one that occurred first, that is why I sort by timestamp asc.

Comment: you have term_id_distinct_count = 3 for user t10 ... but from your data it appears there are only 2 of them ... is it a typo or I dont understand your question

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Most databases that support window functions support `count(distinct)` as a window function, so you can do:

```
select a.term_id, term_id_distinct_count, a.prop_list
from (select user_id, term_id, prop_list,
             row_number() over (partition by term_id order by time_stamp asc) as seqnum,
             count(distinct user_id) over (partition by term_id) as term_id_distinct_count
      from data_table
     ) a
where seqnum = 1;
```